# How to call a C++ member function in python (SWIG)?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to expose my C++ library class to python and be able do call any function contained in that class in python.
My example Library looks like this:

```
#include "example_lib.h"

lib::lib(){};
int lib::test(int i){
return i;
}
```

With the header:

```
class lib{
  lib();
  int test(int i);
};
```

My interface file:

```
/* example_lib.i */
%module example_lib
%{
   /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
   #include "example_lib.h"
%}
%include "example_lib.h"
```

I run the following commands:

```
swig3.0 -c++ -python example_lib.i 
g++ -c -fPIC example_lib.cc example_lib_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.8
g++ -shared -fPIC example_lib.o example_lib_wrap.o -o _example_lib.so
```

but when I try calling the member function
`example_lib.lib.test(1)`,
I only get *type object 'lib' has no attribute 'test'*. How do I make swig expose the member function as well?
It seems like a very basic question but I would appreciate it very much if someone could clarify how it is usually done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default accessibility is `private` in C++, you then need to move it in a `public:` section :

```
class lib{
  public:
    lib();
    int test(int i);
};
```

Also note that `test` is a instance method, you need to instantiate the class.